# PHP dynamically defined variable (to use in a while loop with two conditions)

Tags: php, mysql, variables, while-loop

I thought I would simplify my question and start with trying to solve one problem at a time instead of two. The -1 rating tells me I was not clear enough, so I will try again. My original post is quoted below.

With the following code I can display data from my table that meets the condition that the category is Scenics:

```
<?php
$category = $_GET['category'] ?? 'Scenics';

$sql = "SELECT * FROM photo_library ";
$sql .= "WHERE category='" . $category . "' ORDER BY id ASC";
$image_set = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
$image_set_desc = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
?>
```

What I want to do is have dynamically set. Instead of `$category = $_GET['category'] ?? 'Scenics';`, is there a way not set the way it is above? I would like it be set by whatever it finds in the 'category' column of my SQL table so that later I can say while category is Scenics and sub_category is Coastal, display just that info (so I will need to do something similar for sub_category).

**EDIT:** The term I was looking for was **array**. I want $sub_category to be an **array** based on what is found in the sub_category column of my SQL table.

I am also aware of the risk of using $_GET, but this would be on a protected site where you only get access if you are a member, and you are only a member if you apply and are manually approved for access. And there is no user input in the protected part of the site. It is strictly a resource site for downloading graphics and images.

> I am playing around with having an image gallery be generated using
>   PHP and My SQL instead of coding everything in HTML on the page. I've
>   created a test table that has multiple columns, and a working page
>   where all the info gets pulled in and displayed.
>
> The two main values that will be used to separate image entires from
>   each other are 'category' and 'sub_category'. The page that is working
>   only uses the category and works great.
>
> ```
> <?php
>  $category = $_GET['category'] ?? 'Agroforestry';
>
>  $sql = "SELECT * FROM photo_library ";
>  $sql .= "WHERE category='" . $category . "' ORDER BY id ASC";
>  $image_set = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
>  $image_set_desc = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
> ?>
> ```
>
> $image_set pulls in the info for the actual image, and $image_set_desc
>   does the work for the links and file size. This is the pulling in of
>   the thumbnail:
>
> ```
> <?php while($subject = mysqli_fetch_assoc($image_set)) { ?>
> <li><a href="<?php echo h($subject['jpg_location']); ?>" title="<?php echo h($subject['title']); ?>" data-title="<?php echo
> ```
>
> h($subject['id']); ?>">" src="#" alt="" aria-describedby="">
>
> ```
> <?php while($subject_desc = mysqli_fetch_assoc($image_set_desc)) { ?>    
> <p id="<?php echo h($subject_desc['id']); ?>"><b>Filename:</b> <?php echo h($subject_desc['filename']); ?><br>
> <a class="btn btn-default btn-xs mrgn-tp-sm" role="button" href="<?php echo h($subject_desc['tif_location']); ?>">TIFF <span
> ```
>
> class="wb-inv">image download () ">JPG image
>   download ()
>
> The problem is on the next page I am testing this on, there are a lot
>   more pictures and they are broken up into multiple sub-categories. I
>   only want to display pictures with certain sub-categories under their
>   respective headings.
>
> I am very new to PHP, and do not know how to set something like
>   $sub_category to whatever it finds in that column. I cannot use
>
> ```
> $sub_category = $_GET['sub_category'] ?? 'Coastal';
> ```
>
> because the sub-category needs to be pulled from the SQL table. I
>   don't know what I am doing so while
>
> ```
> $sub_category = isset($_GET['sub_category']);
> ```
>
> doesn't break anything, it also doesn't seem to work. If that somehow
>   works, then
>
> ```
> <?php while(($subject = mysqli_fetch_assoc($image_set)) && ($sub_category == 'Coastal')){ ?>
> ```
>
> is not because nothing is generated on the page. I'm not sure if my
>   problem is with defining $sub_category, the while loop, or both.

Comment: You just need to get sub-category value from font-end and add  condition to your SQL.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add any data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or data *of any kind* directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Note: The [object-oriented interface to `mysqli`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php) is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface where missing a single `i` can cause trouble. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era and should not be used in new code.

Comment: I do not understand any of that. Why do I need to add a condition to my SQL? I am trying to pull info from one of the columns and set it as the value(s) of $sub_category.

The injection bug thing I understand. I just tried '''$_GET''' to see if it would work. Like I said, I just got started with this and know next to nothing, so it needs to be explained to me like I am 7 years old :)

Comment: To simplify my quest ion a bit as a starting point, how do I do something like  $category = $_GET['category'] ?? 'Scenics'; but instead of having $category already set to Scenics, it can be set by whatever it finds in 'category' so that later I can say while category is Scenics and sub_category is Coastal display just that info?

Comment: I still can’t make any sense of what you are trying to ask here. _“I would like it be set by whatever it finds in the 'category' column of my SQL table”_ - if you want records with just _any_ value in the `category` column - well then _remove_ anything that demands a _specific_ value from your WHERE clause …? And if that’s not it - well then you need to explain what you actually want here better, still.

Comment: _“because the sub-category needs to be pulled from the SQL table”_ - are you trying to ask how to get the values from the columns out of your query result set? (Maybe?) Then you should start by checking what your `$subject` variable actually contains - make a `var_dump($subject);` inside the loop, and check what that contains. Is what you are looking for, already in there somehow maybe …?

Comment: I'm pretty sure he just doesn't want to SELECT a specific category, so he should just remove the WHERE clause altogether.

Comment: I want $sub_category to contain all the entries it finds in the sub_category column. That way later in the page when I want it to only show the images from the Scenics category and the Countryside sub-category, I can. Right now `<?php while(($subject = mysqli_fetch_assoc($image_set)) && ($sub_category == 'Countryside')){ ?>` works if I do `$sub_category = 'Countryside';` higher up. I want sub_category to be anything it finds in the column so that I can change `&& ($sub_category == 'Countryside'))` to other values throughout the page.

Comment: I believe the term is array. I want $sub_category to be an array.

Answer (score 0):

First off even if your site is restricted to a subset of users your still leaving room for many attacks which could lead to attackers being able to mess with your database structure and even worse obtain sensitive data.

Regarding your problem please have a look at [normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). Currently every picture has a set category written in the category field which leads to your current confusion/problem because you now want to gather categories from every picture within your database.

If you were to normalize the category field to a separate table and link them via a [foreign key](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-foreign-key/) you could then firstly query all categories and then group the images by the categories after looping trough.

Here's a bit of non optimized pseudo code that should give you an idea as to what I mean:

```php
$categorizedImages = [];
$catSql = "SELECT * FROM categories";
$categories = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
foreach($categories as $category) {
   $imageSql = "SELECT * FROM photo_library WHERE category='" . $category['id'] . "' ORDER BY id ASC";
   // I cant recall if the access from mysqli_query is via array or ->
   $categorizedImages[$category['id']] = mysqli_query($db, $imageSql);
}

var_dump($categorizedImages); exit;
```

Comment: Part of the reason I am using one table is because will not be large (2,600 rows or so) when compared to other SQL tables that can have millions of rows. Another reason is that with one table it will be easier for others to update the table and add new image info to the database if I am absent. Plus the fewer files there are to maintain the better. Hard setting the category in my post above is not and issue since each category has its own web page. It's when I try to grab all the sub-categories that I am having issues.

Comment: That is the one that I want to be variable so I can say something like this (but that actually works) `<?php while(($subject = mysqli_fetch_assoc($image_set)) && ($sub_category == 'Coastal')){ ?>`, display all that stuff. If I have to do ` $category = 'Scenics';` and ` $sub_category = 'Coastal' or 'Countryside' or 'Forests';` (I know that code won't work), it's not the end of the world, but I know that there is a better way to do it.